# How to scan links in a PDF document?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, quartz-graphics

How can I scan links in a PDF Document? Do I have to use Quartz? Which methods/functions?

Comment: What kind of links? Internal document links or links to external (http) resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use Quartz. You have to parse it out from the PDF. This guide can help you.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-TPXREF101

I recommend reading the PDF specification so you will know what to look for.

Comment: can't it be done without Quartz.. :(. i have posted a New Question having similar requirement. can you help me.. :(     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166051/links-inside-pdf-on-webview-are-not-opening-in-a-browser-in-iphone/8166535#8166535

Comment: @Altealice you have any demo of code? Please provide me in swift. I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

The links are stored in the Annotations object so you will need some software to parse those.

Comment: Thanks guy, I didn't know that they are in the Annotations object