# Links inside Pdf on Webview are not opening in a browser in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, pdf, uiwebview

I have parsed urls of pdfs and showing pdf on a webView, but my Links inside webviews are not opening in a browser.i have not used CGPDFDocument. my code is simple :). can anyone help me out.i have seen many similar questions but all are using Quartz.

code :-

```
@class AppDelegate_iPhone;
@interface PdfShowViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *pdfWebview;
    AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate;
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *myIndicator;
    IBOutlet UIProgressView *progress;

    NSURLRequest* DownloadRequest;
    NSURLConnection* DownloadConnection;

    long long bytesReceived;
    long long expectedBytes;
    IBOutlet UILabel *downloadLabel;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *downloadLabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *pdfWebview;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *myIndicator;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progress;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSURLRequest* DownloadRequest;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSURLConnection* DownloadConnection;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSURL *openURL;


-(IBAction)onTapBack;

@end



@implementation PdfShowViewController

@synthesize pdfWebview,myIndicator,progress,receivedData,DownloadRequest,DownloadConnection,downloadLabel,openURL;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];

    unsigned char byteBuffer[[receivedData length]];
    [receivedData getBytes:byteBuffer];
    NSLog(@"Data === %ld",receivedData);

    NSInteger receivedLen = [data length];
    bytesReceived = (bytesReceived + receivedLen);
    NSLog(@"received Bytes ==  %f",bytesReceived);

    if(expectedBytes != NSURLResponseUnknownLength) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Expected Bytes in if ==  %f",expectedBytes);
        NSLog(@"received Bytes in if ==  %f",bytesReceived);

        float value = ((float) (bytesReceived *100/expectedBytes))/100;
        NSLog(@"Value ==  %f",value);
        progress.progress=value;
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [connection release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
    NSLog(@"%f",expectedBytes);

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    [myIndicator stopAnimating];
    [myIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    [progress setHidden:YES];
    [downloadLabel setHidden:YES];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iPhonePdf.pdf"];

    unsigned char byteBuffer[[receivedData length]];
    [receivedData getBytes:byteBuffer];

    [self.receivedData  writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];

    [DownloadConnection release];

    //Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [pdfWebview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [pdfWebview loadRequest:requestObj];

}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView1 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *requestURL = [request URL];
    if(navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pdfWebview.delegate = self;

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [downloadLabel setText:@"Downloading..."];
    [downloadLabel setHidden:NO];

    [myIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    myIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [myIndicator startAnimating];

    //  NSString *urlString = [appDelegate.currentBookPressed stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *urlString = [appDelegate.currentBookPressed stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//  NSLog(@"The Url Stirng=======%@",urlString);

    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    //NSLog(@"Trageted String ------======++++++++%@",targetURL);
    DownloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:1200.0];
    DownloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:DownloadRequest delegate:self];

    if (DownloadConnection) {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data]retain];
    }

    [pdfWebview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [pdfWebview loadRequest:DownloadRequest];


}

-(IBAction)onTapBack
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}



@end
```

here is the link which i am trying to open but not opening :-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, links inside pdf files loaded in a UIWebView won't open when you tap them by default.

You can go the hard way and parse the links out using Quartz as is shown in [this other post I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717775/how-to-scan-links-in-a-pdf-document/3720381).

Or, instead of loading a pdf, can you convert the content you are loading to an html file instead? That would be easier, and the links should work then.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply.... its a great suggestion, but i wonder how can i convert pdf to html... as i am fetching pdf's url from server.... Actually my requirement is to show some documents of the client uploaded at server on the iPhone. so i choose them to be pdf's. Is there any other way ..??

Comment: So, can you choose for them to be HTMLs instead?

Comment: Hey i think, it couldn't be done, the way i wanted, but as u helped i am ticking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use below delegate method

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView1 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  NSURL *requestURL = [request URL]  ;
   if(navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
   {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
     return NO;
   }
   else
   {
     return YES;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks dude... but can you explain also a little bit for what u have implemented this, as it is not working. :)

Comment: this delegate method will call for every action in webview if you  load any request this method call and any link click you wiil get here UIWebViewNavigationType

Comment: actually it is getting called twice first when i start loading my pdf and secondly after loading my pdf.... but when i click on any link it is not calling this method.... actually it is not recognizing the link.see i am uploading the link image also.